# How to update time field in django

Tags: django

This my table and here i want to update the `end_time` field

For that I get error while updating `end_time` field

> 07/May/2014 07:54:30] "POST /createxml/ HTTP/1.1" 500 13328

**models.py**

```
class JobDetails(models.Model):
    user_id=models.ForeignKey('UserDetails',null=True)
    job_name=models.CharField(max_length=45,null=True)
    start_time = models.TimeField(_(u"Job Start Time"), auto_now_add=True, blank=True,null=True)
    end_time = models.TimeField(_(u"Job End Time"), auto_now_add=True, blank=True,null=True)
    status=models.IntegerField(null=True)
    job_url=models.URLField(null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s%s%s%f%s%s' % (self.id,self.job_name,self.start_time,self.end_time,self.status,self.job_url)
```

**Views.py**

```
job_object=JobDetails.objects.get(pk=jobMaxId)
job_object.status=job_status
job_object.end_time=time.localtime(etime)
job_object.save();
```

Here it successfully update the status field but not `end_time` giving error

When I use `sys.exc_info()` , I got the following error.

```
import sys 
print sys.exc_info()
(<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>, TypeError('expected string or buffer',), <traceback object at 0xb93c098>)
```

Comment: wt error ur getting while updating it?

Comment: Enable DEBUG in your settings to see the stacktrace. Without it we're not able to recognize your Exception

Comment: u can do put the code in try and in except import sys print sys.exc_info()

Comment: (<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>, TypeError('expected string or buffer',), <traceback object at 0xb93c098>)


I get this error after using import sys print sys.exc_info()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `time` with

```
import time
time.localtime(etime)
```

But django `DateTimeField`, and `TimeField` supports `time` module imported as

```
from datetime import time
```

Otherwise, you will get error bacause time formats do not match.

You must first change your `time` format to datetime...

```
from datetime import datetime
from time import mktime, time, localtime

end_time = localtime(etime)
datetime_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime(end_time))  # Convert your time.struct_time to datetime.time

job_object.end_time = datetime_time
job_object.save()
```